# Swagger ui sends POSTs with query parameters instead of body

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

I have a controller method:

```
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage SetKitten([FromBody] string kittenName)
{
   return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
}
```

In Swagger it appears as a POST but when I try it, swagger sends the request using query parameters:

> Request URL
>   localhost.../KittenHandler/SetKitten?kittenName=Boris

This results in an error as it must be in the body.

Any idea why swagger is doing this?

Comment: Can you add the controller and the route configuration? Without them, it's hard to tell.